# Duplicate a named capturing group

Tags: regex

Considering the string

```
aaa"bbb"
```

And the REGEX

```
(?<first>.+?(?="))"(?<first>.+?(?="))
```

We have the named capturing group

```
'first' => aaa
'second' => bbb
```

I want, as result a duplicated capturing group with the same value, like:

```
'first' => aaa
'duplicated' => aaa
'second' => bbb
```

Do you know how can we do this?

Comment: why do you need that? :)

Comment: project related problem :(

Comment: could you post code that's supposed to use duplicate group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a "duplicated" capture group inside the "first" capture group.

```
(?<first>(?<duplicated>.+?(?=")))"(?<second>.+?(?="))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand you at all, but with this pattern you can get your values:

```
Expresion: ^([^\"]*)\"([^\"]*)\"$
String: aaaa"bbb"
Replace: $1__$1__$2
Result: aaaa__aaaa__bbb
```

More info, use

```
http://www.metriplica.com/es/recursos/expresiones-regulares
```